# Text box to accept only numeric values

Tags: vb.net-2010

Text box that accepts only numeric values.
I have a text box for bank account number. Now i want this text box to accept only numeric values.

Comment: use this code <input type="number" name="someid" />

Comment: Exactly as Harsh has said.

Answer (score 0):

```
   `Private Sub Data_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Data.KeyPress
    If (Not e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) And ("0123456789.").IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And Data.Text.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = ".") >  0) Then
        e.Handled = True
      End If
      End Sub
```

`